# "Class 'String' has no instance method " Dart code " visual studio "

Tags: dart

When i write and run this function by dart

```
void main (){
    List names= [ "eslam", "zoz", "semsem"];

    var name = names.any((element) => element > 3);

    print (name);
}
```

show me

```
Exception has occurred.
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class 'String' has no instance method '>'.
Receiver: "eslam"
Tried calling: >(3))
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you meant to compare the *length* of the string, rather than the string itself to `3`.

```
var name = names.any((element) => element.length > 3);
```